# Recreate contextmenu event in RxJS

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I want to recreate the [contextmenu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event) event from touch events in RxJS because iOS [does not support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event#browser_compatibility) the contextmenu event on touch.

In plain language, this observable should emit when:

- the touchstart event occurred
- for 2000ms (basically long-press)
- followed by touchend

It should not emit when:

- the touchend occurs in less than 2000ms
- the touchstart event is followed by touchmove event

I can't figure out how to skip if the touchend occurs sooner or if the touchstart is followed by touchmove. This is what I've so far:

```
const touchStart$ = fromEvent<TouchEvent>(this.el.nativeElement, "touchstart");
const touchEnd$ = fromEvent<TouchEvent>(this.el.nativeElement, "touchend");
const touchMove$ = fromEvent<TouchEvent>(this.el.nativeElement, "touchmove");
const contextmenu$ = touchStart$.pipe(
      switchMap(event => touchEnd$.pipe(mapTo(event))),
      switchMap(event => timer(2000).pipe(mapTo(event), takeUntil(merge(touchEnd$, touchMove$))))
);

contextmenu$.subscribe($event => {
      console.log("CONTEXTMENU EVENT HAPPENED");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution can be simplified a little bit.  The inner `mapTo` isn't necessary, if you don't reuse the name `event`, you can just use a single `mapTo` at the end of your pipe.  Also, you may want to use `take(1)` instead of `takeUntil(touchMove$)` on the inner `switchMap` since you want to end the stream after the first emission:

```js
  const longPress$ = this.touchStart$.pipe(
    switchMap(event => timer(2000).pipe(
      takeUntil(merge(touchMove$, touchEnd$)),
      switchMap(() => touchEnd$.pipe(take(1))),
      mapTo(event)
    ))
  );
```

I'm assuming you got the behavior you wanted, but I think normally a longpress will fire when duration passes; i.e. we needn't wait for the `touchend` event.  If that were the case, it gets even simpler:

```js
  const longPress$ = this.touchStart$.pipe(
    switchMap(event => timer(2000).pipe(
      takeUntil(merge(touchMove$, touchEnd$)),
      mapTo(event)
    ))
  );
```

Here are a couple StackBlitzes with colorful logging: [Original](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-72301006-original?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) | [Simplified](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-72301006?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a possible solution:

```
const touchStart$ = fromEvent<TouchEvent>(this.el.nativeElement, "touchstart");
const touchEnd$ = fromEvent<TouchEvent>(this.el.nativeElement, "touchend");
const touchMove$ = fromEvent<TouchEvent>(this.el.nativeElement, "touchmove");
const contextmenu$ = touchStart$.pipe(
    switchMap(event =>
        timer(2000).pipe(
           mapTo(event),
           takeUntil(merge(touchMove$, touchEnd$)),
           switchMap(event => touchEnd$.pipe(mapTo(event), takeUntil(touchMove$)))
        )
    )
);

contextmenu$.subscribe($event => {
    console.log("CONTEXT MENU EVENT HAPPENED");
});
```